# D3 js force layout: setting node radius with link parameter

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I am trying to set the node radius with a parameter `value` from within my json link data. The nodes and links have the following formats

```
"nodes": {"name": "Flare", "group": 1}, 
"links": {"source": 0, "target": 1, "value": 10}
```

It works fine to set the node radius using the `d.group` parameter like so:

```
nodes.append("circle")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("r", function (d) { return d.group})
```

Although a similar idea using the link `d.value` does not work:

```
nodes.append("circle")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("r", function (d) { return d.value })
```

How does one go about pulling the data from links?

Comment: that is because, links are for lines and nodes are for circle. So, the link data is not bound to node data. Print the d to check what the it contains

Comment: Ok thanks, I get it. I called 'd' for a node attribute and it displayed the nodes data and then called 'd' within 'linkDistance' and it returned the links data. So, the next question, is there a way to set node size with a link parameter? I am changing the link data dynamically and need to change the node sizes for each set of links.

Comment: problem is number of nodes and links are not equal. I don't know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to assign the size of the target node with the 'value' parameter in the links data. The source node is always the parent of all of the target nodes, i.e. always only one level of hierarchy. The parent node should be assigned a size separately. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the modified function, there I am modifying the nodes data to add the value data from links. I hope this is what you are looking for.

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 4, height / 4));


  var graph = {
  "nodes": [
    {"id": "Myriel", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Napoleon", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Mlle.Baptistine", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Mme.Magloire", "group": 1},
    {"id": "CountessdeLo", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Geborand", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Champtercier", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Cravatte", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Count", "group": 1},
    {"id": "OldMan", "group": 1}
  ],
  "links": [
    {"source": "Napoleon", "target": "Myriel", "value": 13},
    {"source": "Mlle.Baptistine", "target": "Myriel", "value": 8},
    {"source": "Mme.Magloire", "target": "Mlle.Baptistine", "value": 6},
    {"source": "CountessdeLo", "target": "Myriel", "value": 10},
    {"source": "Geborand", "target": "Myriel", "value": 16},
    {"source": "Champtercier", "target": "Myriel", "value": 17},
    {"source": "Cravatte", "target": "Myriel", "value": 19},
    {"source": "Count", "target": "Myriel", "value": 20},
    {"source": "OldMan", "target": "Myriel", "value": 8}
  ]
};
  var link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

function modified () {
  for(var j = 0 ; j < graph.nodes.length ; j++) {
   for(var i = 0 ; i < graph.links.length ; i++) {
    if(graph.nodes[j].id == graph.links[i].source) {
     graph.nodes[j].value = graph.links[i].value;
     break;
    }
   }
  }
  return graph.nodes;
}
  var node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(modified())
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", function (d) { 
  if(d.value == NaN) {
   d.value = 5;
  }
  return d.value })
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id; });

  simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  }

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}
```

```css
.links line {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

.nodes circle {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
```